# Как создать диаграмму классов в VS2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Я не понимаю как сделать диаграмму классов у меня просто нет такой возможности добавить ее как это сделать?

Comment: А у тебя установлен модуль для этого?

Comment: А какой нужен модуль?

Comment: "Конструктор классов" в Visual Studio Installer посмотри

Comment: Не нужен никакой модуль, в контекстном меню для интересующего файла есть пункт View class diagram.